# pleas check your network connection android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

this is my problem click in this :

[image]

**Error is**

> install failed . pleas check your network  connection and try again

Comment: do you have a safe internet connection?

Comment: Try to run with admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by some kind of incompatibility with HTTPS.

For solve this, in the Android SDK Manager, go to "Options" in the "Tools" menu, and check the option "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...".

Then try again to download the package.